# solve the integral of gaussian random vector

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, definite-integrals, random-variables

I have a hypotheses testing problem of Gaussian random vector. It is a hypothesis testing problem. In the Hypotheses
 H0: $\textbf{$y=s_{0}+\eta$}$ $\\$ and

in hypotheses H1: $\textbf{$y=s_{1}+\eta$} $ . where , $\eta$ is a complex gaussian random vector $N(0,\sigma^2)$, and $s_0$ and $s_1$ are complex sequences of length $N$.
So $\textbf{$y$}$ is also of length $N$. After applying a maximum likelihoof decision rule, i've obtained a threshold $\lambda$.
So i have this integral $$P_{fa}=\int_\lambda^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{\Vert \textbf{y}-s_0 \Vert^2 }{2\sigma^2} \right) \, d\textbf{y}, \tag 1$$ to calculate the probabilty of false alarm. I do not know what substitution to solve this integral.

Now to find the false alarm, my colleague suggesed an othe method to use. In the second method you find individual $\lambda_i's$ for each element in $\textbf{y}$. and to find the probability of false alarm, multiply the individual integrals

$$P_{fa}=\int_{\lambda_2}^\infty \int_{\lambda_2}^\infty \cdots\int_{\lambda_n}^\infty \exp \left(-\frac{\Vert \textbf{y}-s_0 \Vert^2 }{2\sigma^2} \right) \, dy_1 \, dy_2 \cdots dy_n, $$ because each of the element is i.i.d.

Now i have two questions, is the second method valid? (i'm skeptical to use it), and how to solve the 1st integral

Comment: What does $\lambda$ to $\infty$ mean? You need to specify what the integral is with respect to.

Comment: I've modified the question accordingly @Batman